# Bandpass in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

In Simulink, I have to create a random signal with total occupied bandwidth of 2kHz in the range from 1kHz to 3kHz. I tried to do it like on screenshots but it didn't work properly. Any idea how to do it?

[image: settings]

[image: spectrum analyser]

Comment: That seems correct to me... what do you consider wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that you designed your filter at 10 kHz sample rate, and not at 20 kHz like your graph seems to say.

Comment: post filter signal has like two bandwidths: 1kHz - 3kHz and 7kHz - 9kHz

Comment: That seems correct to me since you designed your filter with 10 kHz sample rate.

Comment: so I need to change sample rate to get a one specific bandwith?

Comment: I have also one more question:  how to create a two-tone signal in simulink?

Comment: Superposition of two monotone signals: Tone_1(t) + Tone_2(t).

Comment: which blocks in simulink will be appropriate for this task? 2 Sine Wave blocks and sum ?

Comment: Yes, this will do.